# After an OS and VSCode update I cannot use the enter key in VSCode anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code

MAC OS  Venturaa 13.3 (22E252)
VS Code Version: 1.77.0 (Universal)

thanks for the help

Restarted VS Code, restarted computer. ctrl + Enter does not work.

Comment: shift + return or command + return works now. Nothing changed, except restart.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Disabled this Extension !! Enter Will work fine...

Comment: What a legend, you saved my day! Just had the exact same issue and this fixed for me